# Accessing TempData in JavaScript file returns variable instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have assigned value to a `TempData` in the controller action method as below:

```
TempData["FromTask"] = true;
```

I tried to access its value in the `.js` file using below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = '@TempData["FromTask"]';
    alert('data: '+ data);
}
```

But this alerts`data: @TempData["FromTask"]` instead of `data: true`

If I remove quotes in  `'@TempData["FromTask"]';`, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: remove the quotes around `@TempData["FromTask"]`

Comment: If i remove quotes, i am getting like `(Bundler & Minifier) Conditional compilation is turned off: @TempData`

Comment: can you try var data = @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject((bool)TempData["FromMask"])

Comment: still I'm getting same error

Comment: This line `var data = '@TempData["FromTask"]';` needs to be in a location where your ASP.Net code will be interpreted - ie. ***not*** in a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = '@TempData["FromTask"]'=='True'?true:false;
    alert('data: '+ data);
}
```

result:

[image]